# Question about convergence in measure of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is the exercise that I am trying to do:

---

Prove that if $f_{k}$ is a sequence of functions over $E$ that converges to $f$ in measure and $g_{k}$ is a sequence of functions over $E$ that converges in measure to $g$ then  $f_{k}+g_{k}$ converges to $f$+$g$ in measure. Furthermore, if the functions are finite and $m(E)<\infty$ then $f_{k}g_{k}$ converges in measure to $fg$ in the set $E$.

---

I am using Norberto Fava's textbook "*Medida e integral de Lebesgue"* from *Universidad de Buenos Aires.*

**What I have tried:**

if $f_{n}$ converges in measure to $f$ then by definition $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(x\in E: \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2} )=0$. Likewise, if if $g_{n}$ converges in measure to $g$ then by definition $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(x\in E: \mid g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2}  )=0$, for any $\delta>0$. This means we can choose N such that if n$\geq N$ then $ \mu(x\in E: \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2} ) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $ \mu(x\in E: \mid g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2} ) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Adding these two measures we get:

$$ \mu(x\in E: \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid +\mid g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid  \geq \frac{\delta}{2} ) \leq  \mu(x\in E: \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2} ) +  \mu(x\in E: \mid g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2} ) < \epsilon $$

Noting that $$ \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)  + g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid \leq \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid +\mid g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid $$ I think we can conclude that if $n\geq N$

$$ \mu (x\in E:  \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)  + g_{n}(x)-g(x) \mid \geq \frac{\delta}{2}  )< \epsilon $$

**My questions**

a) Is this approach correct? How would you go about it?

b) Can you give me a suggestion for the second part of the exercise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For (a): I think is correct.

For (b): You can use that $a\cdot b=\dfrac{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}{4}$.
So you only need to show that $f_n^2\to f^2$ if $f_n\to f$.